# Celery run only one task with the same argument

Tags: celery, django-celery

I am working with celery & Django
My app have a feature with the flow:

- User upload a file called A
- The system handle file A with a total of 3 step that don't need a strict order. Each step is considered as one celery task, and passing only id of the uploaded file as argument
- After finish, return the output to user

I want to ensure

- At the same time, one file must be handle by only one step
- At the same time, each step can handle multiple files
  How can I do it?